# Android Dynamic Database SQLite Storage Best Practice

Tags: android, arrays, dynamic, android-sqlite

I was wondering if anyone has had a situation where they needed a truly dynamic or appearing dynamic database field in android sqlite.

Let me elaborate.

I would like to create two separate fields in my database that can vary in storage length. For example I have two fields `sprints` and `sprint_time`. So basically I want a user to be able to select the amount of sprints they are going to do, which I will create as an `array` like `String [] sprints = new String [userEnteredValue];` where `int userEnteredValue;` will specify the amount of sprints they will do, and then I want to loop through adding in a `string` at each position like

```
for(int i = 1; i < sprints.length;i++){
 sprints[i] = "Sprint_"+i;
 }
```

i then want to use `int userEnteredValue;` to create the second array but only as place holders for the times for each sprint. This is where I am getting confused. So obviously I just create another `array` as such `String [] sprint_time = new String [userEnteredValue];` and loop through this array to create the place holders like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sprint_time.length; i++){
 sprint_time[i] = "SprintTime_"+i; // place holder for each sprint time
 }
```

After I create both of these in my android activity I want the user to be able to enter in the times once they have completed each `sprints[i]`

I know in order to store these values in a db i need to turn each `array` into a `String`, this is not my question of how to do this.

My question is more of has anyone done this and is there an example I can go off of?
Also, is this the best way to achieve this or should I be using a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use more tables and do it a little differently, for example I'd probably have two tables, Workouts, and SprintTimes

```
[Workouts   ]     [SprintTimes    ]
|           |     |ID             |
|ID         |  -> |WorkoutID      |
                  |SprintPosition |
                  |Time           |
```

I'm not sure if it's workouts that you're talking about but the setup would be similar.

you'd create a Workout then create a row for every sprint that points back to the workout.

Doing this will also make your queries easier and not have to be built dynamically.  for example, you can get the total time of a workout with a group by and sum:

`select WorkoutID, SUM(Time) from SprintTimes group by WorkoutID`

Comment: hmm nice okay cool I will give this a try. Yeah it would be considered a workout object. I just tried to make it simpler for concept sake. My last approach restricted the user from editing each time. So basically they had to create a workout and each successive set had to be the same amount of reps or in this context each successive sprint would have to be the same time, which is no good for the user and usability . I thought i may be approaching this wrong. Thanks for the input. If my attempt is successful or not i will post updated code and more questions